# How to set a source files directory recursively in gdb?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to debug a program in gdb with a functions source code but I always need to set the EXACT path of the C file for that function:

```
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld$ gdb -q char_array
Reading symbols from char_array...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   
4       int main() {
5           char str_a[20];
6   
7           strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
8           printf(str_a);
9       }
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11c6: file char_array.c, line 6.
(gdb) break strcpy
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1040
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x11dc: file char_array.c, line 8.
(gdb) dir ~/Documents/glibc-2.28/sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch
Source directories searched: /home/frinto/Documents/glibc-2.28/sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) cont
The program is not being run.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/frinto/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld/char_array 

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array.c:7
7           strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, strcpy_ifunc () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c:29
29  libc_ifunc_redirected (__redirect_strcpy, strcpy, IFUNC_SELECTOR ());
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
```

How can I tell gdb to recursively look for `strcpy.c` in `~/Documents/glibc-2.28` without having to set the exact path every single time?

```
frinto@kali:~/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld$ gdb -q char_array
Reading symbols from char_array...done.
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <string.h>
3   
4       int main() {
5           char str_a[20];
6   
7           strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
8           printf(str_a);
9       }
(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11c6: file char_array.c, line 6.
(gdb) break strcpy
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1040
(gdb) break 8
Breakpoint 3 at 0x11dc: file char_array.c, line 8.
(gdb) dir /home/frinto/Documents/glibc-2.28
Source directories searched: /home/frinto/Documents/glibc-2.28:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/frinto/Documents/theclang/programs/helloworld/char_array 

Breakpoint 1, main () at char_array.c:7
7           strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, strcpy_ifunc () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c:29
29  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main () at char_array.c:8
8           printf(str_a);
(gdb)
```

I tried just setting the glibc directory but that doesn't work...

Comment: regarding: `(gdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11c6: file char_array.c, line 6.`  this breakpoint will never occur because line 6 is a blank lline

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `(gdb) info source` when it's stopped at the strcpy breakpoint?

Comment: Did you get it working ~@user10199821 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is common to build GLIBC this way:

```
cd glibc-2.28 && mkdir build && cd build && ../configure --prefix=/usr && make
```

This results in source paths similar to `../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy.c` (they are relative to the `build` directory).

So what you want is:

```
cd ~/Documents/glibc-2.28 && mkdir build; cd -
gdb -ex 'dir ~/Documents/glibc-2.28/build' -q char_array
```